# Elements reverting back to original sizes after JQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

So I am trying to get my header to change its size to become smaller after the user scrolls a certain distance down the page, the animations for the header to get bigger and smaller execute at the right time. Only issue is on the animation to make the header bigger, the animation happens as it should but as soon as it has finished animated the header reverts back to its original size for some reason. Not sure if this makes any difference but the header has its position set to fixed in the css. I have never come across an issue like this so have no idea what is going wrong, and googling it hasn't helped me either.

You can view the issue here: http://eventrem.com

Full Javascript:

```
function getScrollOffsets() {

    var doc = document, w = window;
    var x, y, docEl;

    if ( typeof w.pageYOffset === 'number' ) {
        x = w.pageXOffset;
        y = w.pageYOffset;
    } else {
        docEl = (doc.compatMode && doc.compatMode === 'CSS1Compat')?
            doc.documentElement: doc.body;
        x = docEl.scrollLeft;
        y = docEl.scrollTop;
    }

    return {x:x, y:y};
}

var IsHeaderBig;

window.onload = function() {

    var offset = getScrollOffsets();

    if (offset.y > 100) {
        IsHeaderBig = false;
        animateHeaderSmall(0);  
    } else {
        IsHeaderBig = true;
        animateHeaderBig(0);    
    }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){

    var offset =  getScrollOffsets();

    if (offset.y > 100) {

        //Make Small    
        if (IsHeaderBig) {

            IsHeaderBig = false;
            animateHeaderSmall(300);
        }

    } else {

        //Make Big  
        if (!IsHeaderBig) {

            IsHeaderBig = true;
            animateHeaderBig(300);

        }

    }

 });

 function animateHeaderBig(speed) {

    var header = $("#headerContainer");
    var buffer = $("#homeBuffer");

    header.animate({
        height:'548px'
    }, speed, function() {});   

    buffer.animate({
        height:'470px'
    }, speed, function() {});

 }

 function animateHeaderSmall(speed) {

    var header = $("#headerContainer");
    var buffer = $("#homeBuffer");

    header.animate({
        height:'100px'
    }, speed, function() {});   

    buffer.animate({
        height:'100px'
    }, speed, function() {});


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to handle the `complete` function and set the values there.

```
function animateHeaderBig(speed) {

    var header = $("#headerContainer");
    var buffer = $("#homeBuffer");

    header.animate({
        height:'548px'
       }, {
          duration: speed,
          complete: function() {
            $(this).css('height', '548px');
          }
       });

    buffer.animate({
        height:'470px'
       }, {
          duration: speed,
          complete: function() {
                          $(this).css('height', '470px');
          }
       });
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just tried this and still the same issue unfortunately (I have updated eventrem.com to show it).

Comment: @william205 - Could you please do the following tests: 1) Add the line `console.log('Inside animation complete')` in the complete handlers, to confirm that they are being called. 2) Replace `$(this).css` with `header.css`. I might be mistaken as to what the `this` value equals in an animation complete handler.

Comment: no need to do that, your answer actually has fixed it. I completely cleared the cache and everything in chrome and it now works perfectly. Thank you very much